# How to change root directory for ReSharper's suggested namespaces?

Tags: namespaces, resharper

ReSharper wants me to change my namespace to `ProjectName.Assets.Code.SomeNamespace`. This is because this project has its code two folders down from the root of the project.

Is there some way I can set ReSharper to instead suggest `ProjectName.SomeNamespace`? It should assume the root directory for all our code is in ^/Assets/Code.

Answer (score 2):

Select the folder you want to ignore in the `Solution Explorer`, then look at it's properties in the `Property Window`, you should see the setting for `Namespace Provider`, set it to `False`. (So in your case select the `Assets` and `Code` folders

Comment: I have Namespace Provider set to False for both the `Assets` and `Code` directories, yet ReSharper continues to suggest `ProjectName.Assets.Code.SomeNamespace`. Maybe there's something else I need to do? This is also a Unity project so I don't know if that has anything to do with it.

Comment: I've had the same problem with Unity. UnityVS didn't have the same problem though, I believe it has to do with how Unity automatically updates the project files.

Comment: So do you use UnityVS with ReSharper and the namespace suggestions work? Or are you using UnityVS instead of ReSharper? I just discovered VS & ReSharper and wow this is much nicer than MonoDevelop!

Comment: I use UnityVS with ReSharper, and the suggestions work